# C++ const correctness for custom handle types

Tags: c++, const-correctness

I am currently writing some code where I have custom handle types. The code in question looks something very similar to this:

```
struct SegmentData
{
    //...
};

class SegmentHandle
{
public:

    SegmentHandle(Path * _path, int _idx);

    void setPosition(float _x, float _y);

    float positionX() const;

    float positionY() const;


private:

    Path * m_path;
    int m_index;
};

class Path
{
public:

    SegmentHandle segmentHandle(int _idx) const
    {
        // Path object itself can never be const so this should be fine
        return SegmentHandle(const_cast<Path*>(this), _idx);
    }

private:

    std::vector<SegmentData> m_segmentData;
};

Path * path = createPath();
//...add some segments
SegmentHandle seg = path.segmentHandle(3);
seg.setPosition(100, 30);
//...
```

In terms of const correctness this is not very good as we can modify the `Path` data through the `SegmentHandle` despite the getter being const. To fix this I tried having separate types for `const` and non `const` handles (similar to `const_iterator` vs `iterator` in the standard library), i.e.:

```
template<class PT>
class SegmentHandleT
{
public:

    SegmentHandleT(PT * _path, int _idx);

    void setPosition(float _x, float _y);

    float positionX() const;

    float positionY() const;


private:

    PT * m_path;
    int m_index;
};

using SegmentHandle = SegmentHandleT<Path>;
using ConstSegmentHandle = SegmentHandleT<const Path>;
```

While this seems fine in a simple example like this, in a real world codebase where you have multiple interacting handle types it explodes the code complexity significantly, introduces templates where they otherwise would not be used/needed etc..
This seriously tempts me to stick with option 1 as technically the function does not directly modify the underlying path object. Are there any other options to maintain a greater level of *const correctness* in a scenario like this where the trade-off between code complexity and real world gain is more balanced?

Thanks!

Comment: "Path object itself can never be const" - why is that? That `const_cast` seems to be a straight shot in the leg. You should rather make two independent methods - one (const qualified) returning immutable segment handle and another one returning mutable segment handle. Also this "handle" type looks more like an array view.

Comment: @VTT Isn't an array view usually a (sub)range of an array rather than just one item? The actual path is created on the heap through a factory function which can't create a const version. Despite that, I agree that the main getter function should be the non const version. How do you feel about the fact that you could still modify the path data through the handle returned from the const function though? Thanks!

Comment: Having different types for `Path` and `Path const` seems like a viable solution.